# Python factory pattern - object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, class, factory, abstract, radix

I am working on some python code - trying to implement composition and factory pattern:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
import configparser
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys



class LoggerAbstract(ABC):

  def __init__(self, option_one=option_one_value, option_two=option_two_value): 
    pass

  def read_configurations(self, configurations_dict): 
    pass
    
  def write_message(self, message): 
    pass
      

class MyLogger(LoggerAbstract):

  def __init__(self, option_one=option_one_value, option_two=option_two_value): 

    super().read_configurations(self.configurations_dict)

  def write_message(self, message): 
    pass
    

class MyLoggerCritical(MyLogger):

  def __init__(self, option_one=option_one_value, option_two=option_two_value): 

  def write_message(self, message): 
    pass


class MyLoggerDebug(MyLogger):

  def __init__(self, option_one=option_one_value, option_two=option_two_value): 

  def write_message(self, message): 
    pass


class MyLoggerFactory(MyLoggerCritical, MyLoggerDebug):

  log_factory = {
    "critical": None,
    "debug": None,
  }


  def __init__(self, option_one=option_one_value, option_two=option_two_value): 

    self.log_factory['critical'] = MyLoggerCritical(option_one="John", option_two="Doe")
    self.log_factory['debug'] = MyLoggerDebug(option_one="John", option_two="Doe")



class LogFactoryDriver:

  def __init__(): 
  
    my_logger_factory = MyLoggerFactory()
    my_logger_factory['critical'].write_log_message("this is a message")


def main():
  
  my_logger_factory_driver = LogFactoryDriver()
  
if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

The issue I am running into is calling the write_message() method.  My gut feeling is that using a dictionary to create a factory is a bad idea.  Everything I read so far, mentions using dictionary value to store different method names.

Is it possible to assign objects into dictionary values and then call those object's methods?  It doesn't seem to like the call:

```
   my_logger_factory['critical'].write_log_message("this is a message")
```

Throws the following error:

```
TypeError: 'MyLoggerFactory' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: As the code is written, you need `my_logger_factory.log_factory['critical']`.

Comment: If you *do* want to write `'my_logger_factory['critical']`, you need to create an implementation of `MyLoggerFactory.__get_item__`.

Comment: "My gut feeling is that using a dictionary to create a factory is a bad idea." No it isn't. In any case, the error here is very simple. `my_logger_factory = MyLoggerFactory()` is a `MyLoggerFactory` object. You then use `my_logger_factory['critical']`.... **what do you expect to happen**? Currently, `MyLoggerFactory` objects are **not subscriptable**, hence the error. In any case, in the future, **please** provide a [mcve]. The majorit of this code is completely irrelevant (and it isn't even complete!)

Comment: This isn't really even a factory, since you are just instantiating all the different types in `__init__`

Comment: Thank you both.  @juanpa.arrivillaga, I was hasty when I cobbled together the code from the actual code I was working with.  Could you share a example/sample code that leverages Factory Pattern?  

Anyway, I fixed up the code and posted it here.

Answer (score 0):

The code I posted originally was incomplete as @juanpa.arrivillaga pointed out.  Here is the code with the fixes:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
import configparser
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys



class LoggerAbstract(ABC):

  def __init__(self, option_one="John", option_two="Doe"): 
      pass

  def read_configurations(self, configurations_dict): 
      pass
    
  def write_log_message(self, message): 
      pass
      

class MyLogger(LoggerAbstract):

  def __init__(self, option_one="John", option_two="Doe"): 

    super().read_configurations()

  def write_log_message(self, message): 
      pass
    

class MyLoggerCritical(MyLogger):

  def __init__(self, option_one="John", option_two="Doe"): 
    pass

  def write_log_message(self, message): 
      print(f"The message received is: {message}")


class MyLoggerDebug(MyLogger):

  def __init__(self, option_one="John", option_two="Doe"):
    pass 

  def write_log_message(self, message): 
      pass


class MyLoggerFactory(MyLoggerCritical, MyLoggerDebug):

  log_factory = {
    "critical": None,
    "debug": None,
  }


  def __init__(self, option_one="John", option_two="Doe"): 

    self.log_factory['critical'] = MyLoggerCritical(option_one="John", option_two="Doe")
    self.log_factory['debug'] = MyLoggerDebug(option_one="John", option_two="Doe")

  def write_log_message(self, message):
    print(f"Message received is: {message}") 


class LogFactoryDriver:

  def __init__(self, option_one="John", option_two="Doe"): 
  
    my_logger_factory = MyLoggerFactory()
    my_logger_factory.log_factory['critical'].write_log_message("this is a message")


def main():
  
  my_logger_factory_driver = LogFactoryDriver()
  
if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```